# AngularJS Ignoring $http.default.headers

Tags: angularjs

Angular v1.3.5

I'm trying to pass serialized data to my API.  It requires the `Content-Type` header to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;`

For POST, I've set this up as follows in my `.run`:

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;";
```

This works great for POST.  However, for PUT doing the same is completely ignored.

```
$http.defaults.headers.put["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;";
```

I even tried putting this in the request.  The Content-Type was still ignored.

```
$http({
  method : 'PUT',
  url : SMARTWORX_CONFIGS.APIURL + 'users/' + service.profile.id + '.json',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;'
  },
  data : {
    user : profile
  }
})
```

I've been forced to solve this by using an interceptor and adding the headers to the config object there.  It's quite a hack, but it works.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

After beating my head on the wall some more, I discovered the problem - of my own making.

My app is using tokens for authentication; so, I have an interceptor to inject the token into the headers when needed.  I made a mistake with this.

It looked like :

```
config.headers = config.header || {};
config.headers['X-AUTH-TOKEN'] = result;
```

It SHOULD have been written like:

```
config.headers = config.headers || {};
config.headers['X-AUTH-TOKEN'] = result;
```

Basically, I was blowing out all previous headers.